# Vacancy or no vacancy?

Tags: code-golf, color

We've all seen the signs on motels telling us if there's a vacancy or not:

[image]

Typically, these will permanently have the letters of **VACANCY** lit up, and have the letters of **NO** lit up if there isn't any room in the motel.

## The challenge

The average motel in the U.S. has 200 rooms.

You will write a program/function that takes an integer **T** (for taken rooms) as its only input.
Your program will then display the words `NO VACANCY`. The letters of `VACANCY` will be printed in red.
If **T** ≥ 200, the letters of `NO` will also be printed in red.

For example, assuming `a.out` is your program and "input" = command line argument:
[image]
<sup>(I typo'd and my system ignores case.)</sup>

## The rules

- Your program/function must **display** (or, if lambda, [return](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/61563)) the exact string `NO VACANCY`, including case.
- Your program/function may only set the text foreground color to red and not the background.
- If you wish, you may use ANSI escape codes to print the red color - `\x1b[31m` will work.
- Your program/function may not change the text color of your shell after it finishes.
- Your program/function must terminate normally.
- Your program/function must print only to standard output.
- Your program/function must use your shell/terminal/IDE's default background color. (If you choose to have graphical output you may choose whatever color you like, except red.)
- If **T** ≤ 200, the letters of `NO` must be printed in your shell/terminal/IDE's default foreground color. (If you choose to have graphical output, once again you may choose whatever color you like)
- If for some reason your shell/terminal/IDE's default foreground/background color is red, you must print with a black background and a default white foreground.
- If you choose to use graphical output, red may only be used when specified in the program (e.g. your background color or default text color may not be red).

## The winner

As usual with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins! Brownie points for graphical output.
I'll accept the shortest answer in a week. Happy golfing!

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=123146,OVERRIDE_USER=61563;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: There is a conflicting rule: in and above the screenshot, it says to print NO in red "If T ≥ 200". Later, you say to print in the default color "If T ≤ 200"

Comment: @Arc676 Oops. Well, logically, if the hotel has 200 rooms then it must be the first description that is correct.

Comment: For extra credit, do it for the Hilbert Hotel, which has an infinite number of rooms.

Comment: Are these outputs valid: http://i.imgur.com/221Qxgj.png ?

Comment: @sergiol Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
<200o-“NO“ɓ31m”m“=ȤŻ»Œu“ɓm
```

This uses `<CSI>` (**0x9b**), which is shorter than `<ESC>[` (**0x1b 0x5b**).

It resets the foreground color with `<CSI>m` instead of `<CSI>0m`, as the **0** is implicit.

#### Verification

Note that your terminal emulator (e.g., Konsole) must be set to ISO 8859-1 or similar.

[image: screenshot]

#### How it works

```
<200o-“NO“ɓ31m”m“=ȤŻ»Œu“ɓm  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

<200                        Compare with 200, yielding 1 if true, 0 if not.
    o-                      Logical OR -1; map 0 to -1 (and 1 to 1).
      “NO“ɓ31m”             Yield ["NO", "\x9b31m"].
               m            Take the list "modulo" 1 or -1, keeping it as is for 1,
                            reversing it for -1.
                “=ȤŻ»       Implicitly print the previous result and yield the
                            string " vacancy". This is achieved by indexing into
                            Jelly's in-built dictionary.
                     Œu     Convert to uppercase.
                       “ɓm  Implicitly print the previous result and yield the
                            string "\x9bm", which is printed on exit.
```

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript (ES6), 60 bytes

(Open your browser's console while running the snippet to see the colored result.)

[image: screenshot]

```js
f=
n=>console.log((n>199?'%cNO':'NO%c')+' VACANCY','color:red')
```

```html
<input oninput=f(this.value)>
```

Comment: `NO%c VACANCY color:red`?

Comment: @MDXF check your actual browser console. the snippet console emulator doesn't support it.

Comment: Oh, good catch. +1

Comment: Standard JS rules allow you to shorten this greatly. Remove `console.log()` as the rules specify that returns are fine, you do not have to define the function as well.

Comment: @MayorMonty this solution specifically takes advantage of [console.log functionality](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) to create the colored text, so I would feel weird not including it.

Comment: I just learned that you can have colored output on the browser console. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) (*nix style terminal), <s>54</s> <s>48</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to Value Ink*

*`␛` stands in for a literal esc byte (ASCII 27)*

```ruby
->x{"#{x>199?"␛[31m":p}NO␛[31m VACANCY␛[m"}
```

A port of my python answer, that is <s>a byte</s> several bytes shorter.  I'm new to ruby golf but eager to learn so feedback is appreciated.

Comment: `->x{"#{x>199?"␛[31m":p}NO␛[31m VACANCY␛[m"}` saves a byte. The trick is the fact that in string interpolation, `"#{nil}"` will evaluate to an empty string, and `p` can be used as a substitute for `nil`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (*nix style terminal), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```python
lambda x:"\033[31m"*(x-199)+"NO\033[31m VACANCY\033[m"
```

---

This uses ANSI escape codes.  `\033[31m` Makes the terminal red,  if x is less than 200 we will start with one making `NO` red, otherwise we will have one after `NO` making it red anyway.  When we are done `\033[m` clears the color from the terminal.

Comment: The multiplication of the color string instead of a condition is brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

## HTML, <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```html
<input min=200 type=number><x>NO <y>VACANCY<style>:valid+x,y{color:red}
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using the correct wording...

Comment: Oh my... I need a vacation.

Comment: One of the other answers defines CSS separately. If you do that too, you could save 7 chars with "<style>" (pun intended)

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), <s>102</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> 51 bytes

Yes, Java. :P This only works on *nix terminals.

```java
x->(x>199?"\033[31m":"")+"NO\033[31m VACANCY\033[m"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>82</s> 81 bytes

This only works on *nix terminals. <s>I wonder how easy it would be to port this to Java...</s> [Done.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123161/68615)

```
func f(x int)string{v:="NO\033[31m VACANCY\033[m";if(x>199){v=v[2:7]+v};return v}
```

Comment: I see a Java port coming.

Comment: Ninja'd by 11 seconds. XD

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>76</s> <s>73</s></sub> 72 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input of expected type `Integer` from cell `[A1]` and outputs a (NO) VACANCY sign across cells `A2:B2`

```vba
[A2]="NO":[B2]="VACANCY":Range([If(A1>199,"A2:B2","B2")]).Font.Color=255
```

-3 Bytes for changing `rgbRed` to `255`

Comment: Sorry if this is incorrect, I'm not fluent with Excel. But did you mean to write `iif`, and does this return the correct value if the input is equal to 200? `[A1]>200` makes me think otherwise.

Comment: @MDXF Yes, I did mean to write `iif` (abbreviated from `i`nline `if`) however, you are right that should be `>199`rather than `>200` good catch!

Answer (score 3):

### BASH / MKSH, <s>48 47</s> 46 bytes

```
(($1>199))&&a=^[[31m;echo $a^MNO ^[[31mVACANCY^[[m
```

Note: ^[ means 1 byte wide ESC character: 0x1b or decimal 27.

^M means 1 byte wide CR character: 0x0d, decimal 13.

Answer (score 3):

## bash, 41 bytes

```
echo ␛[$[($1>199)*31]mNO ␛[31mVACANCY␛[0m
```

where ␛ represents a literal ESC character (ASCII \033).

Comment: brilliant multiplication!

Answer (score 2):

## Bash script, 60 bytes

```
c="\e[1;31m";((199<$1))&&printf $c;printf "NO$c VACANCY\e[m"
```

Comment: Just so you know, the downvote was cast automatically by the Community user when your answer was edited. [I consider this a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/170332).

Comment: @MDXF Input is via command-line arguments.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, my bad. You may want to change the header to `Bash script, 64 bytes`.

Comment: Unless you literally make hundred of edits, you can edit your answer every time you get an idea. Edits within the same 5-minute window get grouped into a single revision anyway.

Comment: This doesn't reset the terminal color at the end, which is required.

Comment: Save a byte by changing `200<=$1` to `199<$1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

EDIT:

- -1 byte: From @Dennis's Jelly answer, the `0` argument in the final escape sequence can be dropped.

`f` takes an integer and returns a string. Use as `putStrLn$f 200`.

```hs
f t|t>199="\27[31m"++f 0|0<1="NO \27[31mVACANCY\27[m"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#y03MzLPNzCtJLUpMLlEpzcvJzEst1stNLNBI0ytKTUzR1CvPL0op/p@mUFJTYmdoaWmrFGNkHm1smKukrZ2mYFBjYGNoq@TnrwAVDXN0dvRzjgTxcpX@/zdQMDVQAOpSMDIwUDA2MAAA) Alas, the colors don't show up in TIO, but you can see that the ANSI codes are correctly placed.

Golfing seemed to peter out pretty quickly with this one - not even naming the escape strings seems to save anything. The cleverest bit is recursing with `f 0` to use the other branch as a substring. Three different attempts at using list comprehensions all turned up one byte longer. Perhaps the nicest I found:

```hs
f t=foldr drop"\27[31mNO \27[31mVACANCY\27[m"[5|t<200]
```

Comment: 54 byte alternative: `f t=concat["\27[31m"|t>199]++"NO \27[31mVACANCY\27[0m"`.

Comment: @Laikoni Oh! I was so close to that but somehow never noticed `concat` was shorter than `id=<<` because of the parentheses.

Comment: @Laikoni With Dennis's tip that's also 53 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript (ES6), <s>74</s> 59 bytes

Takes input as function argument of `f`, like `f(100)`.

#### HTML

```
<x id=n>NO <j id=r>VACANCY
```

#### CSS

```
#r{color:red
```

#### JavaScript (ES6)

```
f=a=>a>199?n.id="r":0
```

### Test Snippet

```js
f=a=>a>199?n.id="r":0

f(prompt("Enter a number"))
```

```css
#r{color:red
```

```html
<x id=n>NO <j id=r>VACANCY
```

Comment: Gah that [unclosed curly bracket](https://xkcd.com/859/) is awful...

Comment: @BetaDecay HAHA! LOL! :D

Comment: @BetaDecay I feel with you.... It hurts deep down in your <s>heart</s> assembly level code...

Comment: -1: `f=a=>n.id=a>199&&"r"`

Comment: Get rid of second element's id and set the CSS rule selector to `j,#r` to save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## BASH, 100 bytes

```
if(($1<200));then
echo -n NO
else
echo -ne '\033[31mNO\033[0m'
fi
echo -e '\033[31m VACANCY\033[0m'
```

This can be probably be golfed, but I'm low on time. I'll come back to this later.

-5 bytes thanks to @R. Kap

Comment: Replacing `if [ $1 -le 200 ]` with `if(($1<200))` saves 5 bytes and fixes the bug of the output not appearing in all red with an input of `200`.

Comment: @R.Kap Thanks. OP requested default color for less than or equal to 200 though.

Comment: No, OP asked for all red ouput for inputs more than or equal to 200.

Answer (score 1):

## C (*nix style terminal), <s>50</s> <s>55</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

<sup>-1 thanks to Wheat Wizard</sup>

```
f(t){printf("␛[%dmNO ␛[31mVACANCY␛[m",t>199?31:0);}
```

␛ stands for the literal ESC byte, ASCII 27.

Call with `f(200)`, 200 being the number. Prints `NO VACANCY` colored to the spec.

Comment: In my terminal, that breaks your rule that it shouldn't change the text color of the shell.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Fixed. I forgot that I run a custom shell which automatically sets the color.

Comment: You can change `␛[0m` to `␛[m`

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
Print[s=Style[#,FontColor->Red]&;If[#>200,s,#&]@"NO",s@" VACANCY"]&
```

or (60 bytes, but may be considered cheating)
This is actually `Times["NO","VACANCY"]`, but appear to be correct.

```
(s=Style[#,FontColor->Red]&;If[#>200,s,#&]@"NO")s@"VACANCY"&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 47 bytes

```
(If[#>199,Style[NO,Red],NO]Style[VACANCY,Red])&
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 41 bytes

```
␛[<?=$argn<200?31:''?>mNO␛[31m VACANCY␛[m
```

␛ represents the Escape character.

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 48 bytes

```
f(t){R"␛[%dmNO ␛[31mVACANCY␛[m",t>199?31:0
```

Where ␛ stands for ASCII 27, the ESCAPE byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [GW-BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC), <s>78</s> <s>74</s> 65 bytes

<sup>-12 thanks to Orjan Johansen</sup>

```
1INPUT X:IF X>199THEN COLOR 4
2?"NO ";:COLOR 4:?"VACANCY":COLOR 7
```

Prompts user for an integer. Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Hm can't find an online interpreter, but can't line 1 and 2 be joined with `:`?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Wow... can't believe I completely missed that. Thanks, and yeah, there are no online interpreters. However, you can use the first emulator on https://pcjs.org and type `BASICA` to get something close enough, although it may not have color.

Comment: Assuming that emulator is good enough: You *need* a new line before the first `PRINT`. However, you don't need spaces after the line numbers, and `PRINT` can be abbreviated to `?`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen NO WAY. I've used Microsoft BASIC for eight years and I never new about `?`=`PRINT`. Updating...

Comment: You missed the line number spaces, and seem to have a stray lower case `x`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks. (Edited)

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk, 96 bytes

```
grid [label .n -text NO -fg [expr \$argv>199?"red":"tan"]]
grid [label .v -text VACANCY -fg red]
```

[image]